# SignalR Database Update Notification

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, jquery-ajaxq

I am developing an application in ASP.NET MVC 5. In this project, I'm using SignalR to show the updated data in real time. That means when any data changes, then it will be loaded in the application UI. But unfortunately it's not loaded automatically unless I refresh the page.

Here is my code below:

**Hub:**

```csharp
[HubName("statusLog")]
public class StatusLogHub : Hub
{
    [HubMethodName("sendExportStatus")]
    public void SendExportStatus()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StatusLogHub>();
        Clients.All.updateStatus();
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```csharp
public class EmailStatusLogRepository
{
    readonly string _connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

    public IEnumerable<EmailStatusLog> GetExportStatus()
    {
        var messages = new List<EmailStatusLog>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(
                @"SELECT * " +
                @"FROM dbo.EmailStatusLogs " +
                @"WHERE ExportStatus = 1 " +
                    @"AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,Date,101) AS DATETIME)=CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,'" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + @"',101) AS DATETIME)",
                connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;

                var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    messages.Add(item: new EmailStatusLog 
                        { 
                            Id = (int)reader["Id"], 
                            Investor_Code = (string)reader["Investor_Code"], 
                            EmailId = reader["EmailId"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)reader["EmailId"] : "", 
                            Date = (string)reader["Date"], 
                            ReportName = (string)reader["ReportName"], 
                            ExportStatus = (bool)reader["ExportStatus"], 
                            EmailSendStatus = (bool)reader["EmailSendStatus"], 
                            IsActive = (bool)reader["IsActive"] 
                        });
                }
            }
        }

        return messages;
    }
    
    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            StatusLogHub statusLogHub = new StatusLogHub();
            statusLogHub.SendExportStatus();
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Code from where I am updating DB:**

```csharp
public void ExportStatus()
{
    List<EmailStatusLog> lstEmailStatusLog = new List<EmailStatusLog>();
    EmailStatusLog objEmailStatusLog = new EmailStatusLog();
    foreach (var emailItem in lstEmailReceipent)
    {
        EMailDBContext _ctx = new EMailDBContext();
        
        objEmailStatusLog.EmailId = emailItem.stEmailAdd;
        objEmailStatusLog.Investor_Code = emailItem.stInvestor_code;
        objEmailStatusLog.Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        objEmailStatusLog.ReportName = reportName;
        objEmailStatusLog.ExportStatus = IsSuccess;
        objEmailStatusLog.EmailSendStatus = false;
        objEmailStatusLog.IsActive = true;
        
        _ctx.emailStatusLogs.Add(objEmailStatusLog);
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
        
        //StatusLogHub objStatusLogHub = new StatusLogHub();
        //objStatusLogHub.SendExportStatus();
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```csharp
public ActionResult GetExportStatus()
{
    EmailStatusLogRepository objEmailStatusRepository = new EmailStatusLogRepository();
    return PartialView("_exportedReportList", objEmailStatusRepository.GetExportStatus());
}
```

**Javascript:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    //==================signalR
    $(function () {
        var hub = $.connection.statusLog;
        
        hub.client.updateStatus = function () {
            getExportStatus()
        };
        
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            alert("connection started");
            // hub.server.sendExportStatus($('').val());
            getExportStatus();
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });

    function getExportStatus() {
        var tbl = $('#statusTable');
        
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetExportStatus")',
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).success(function (result) {
            tbl.empty().append(result);
        }).error(function () {

        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i want to rewrite all of your code... haha.  when you use SignalR; you should call client-side functions directly from your hub functions and vice versa.  I think in your current architecture you, in `SendExportStatus` you are telling all of the clients to call the server to get the most recent status, BUT you could change `Clients.All.updateStatus();` to `Clients.All.updateStatus("some status message");` and just give them the status or result directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your client script and hub class method.

In the hub method, you need to pass the `GetExportStatus` method as an argument so that the hub will send the data to all clients:

```csharp
[HubName("statusLog")]
public class StatusLogHub : Hub
{
    [HubMethodName("sendExportStatus")]
    public void SendExportStatus()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StatusLogHub>();
        EmailStatusLogRepository el = new EmailStatusLogRepository();
                Clients.All.updateStatus(el.GetExportStatus());
    }
}
```

And on client side:

```js
$(function() {
    var hub = $.connection.statusLog;
    hub.client.updateStatus = function(data) {
        // data contain all the data from repository this will call every time as repository updated
        getExportStatus(data)
    };
    
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        //alert("connection started");
        hub.server.sendExportStatus();
    }).fail(function(e) {
        alert(e);
    });
});


function getExportStatus(data) {
    alert(data);
    // you can put here logic for getting data on html.
}
```

You can refer following link for cross domain:
[How to use SignalR with cross-domain](http://www.niceonecode.com/Q-A/DotNet/CSharp/How-to-use-SignalR-with-cross-domain/20202)

Comment: Thanks @Rahul but I'm getting this error from client side :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendExportStatus' of undefined at following method : .connection.hub.start().done(function() {
               
                hub.server.sendExportStatus();
            }).fail(function(e) {
                alert(e);
            });
        });

Comment: I think hub not created. so check in configuraton

Comment: There is an exception in javascript : hub is undefind

Answer (score 0):

You can try client script as:

```js
$(function() {
    var hubstatusLog = $.connection.statusLog;
    hubstatusLog.client.updateStatus = function(data) {
        // data contain all the data from repository this will call every time as repository updated
        getExportStatus(data)
    };
   
    $.connection.hub.start(function () {
        hubstatusLog.server.sendExportStatus();
    });
});

function getExportStatus(data) {
    alert(data);
    // you can put here logic for getting data on html.
}
```

server hub:

```csharp
[HubName("statusLog")]
public class StatusLogHub : Hub
{
    [HubMethodName("sendExportStatus")]
    public void SendExportStatus()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StatusLogHub>();
        EmailStatusLogRepository el = new EmailStatusLogRepository();
        
        Clients.All.updateStatus(el.GetExportStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul. But actually I have to use hub without generating proxy. Can you please give any suggestion on this ?

Comment: So, you can refer the link http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#genproxy